# How to put an "X" (to clear a text box) inside the text box?

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, reset-button

In my Windows application I would like to put an `X` at the right edge of a text box to clear it.  Similar to what Google is using right now. Check out Google and do a search for anything. You'll see the `X` in the text box as soon as you've started typing something.

I know I can get away with just putting a button next to the text box.  But I would like to do something a bit nicer.

Comment: Should be no problem, if you're using WPF.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? WPF will make this a lot easier I think.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1861166/754438

Comment: check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447089/embed-image-into-a-textbox

Comment: Waqas: That's unrelated a bit, I think, as they look for a way of having interactivity too, not just an image.

Comment: I'm using WinForms.  WPF wasn't around when this program was originally written.  Not much of a need to re-write.  But you're right.  Doing it in WPF is super easy.  Just trying to see if I missed something and maybe I can do this without too much hassle.  I'll look into those other posts.

Comment: There is a solution here, I believe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/15868817/3737790

Answer (score 3):

Who says that google put an X in right end of text box....??

Thats not inside the google search text box. its outside of that textbox. and thats the onlyway you can do it. google use a table in which one td contains textbox while other contains 'X'. They've put some css which makes you feel like the X is inside textbox. Whixh is really not.

here is the html of google's search textbox:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td class="gsib_a"><div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 25px;"><input type="text" maxlength="2048" name="q" id="lst-ib" class="gsfi" autocomplete="off" size="41" title="Search" value="mysql_num_rows" style="border: medium none; padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 2px; margin: 0pt; width: 100%; outline: medium none; top: 1px; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 5; color: transparent;" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"><div class="gsfi" style="top: 1px; padding: 0pt; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; width: 100%; color: silver; z-index: 0; text-align: left; left: 3px;" id="gs_tad0" dir="ltr"></div><div class="gsfi" style="position: absolute; top: 1px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0pt; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 2; left: 3px;" dir="ltr">aol</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; width: 1px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0pt; z-index: 4; left: 14px; visibility: hidden;"></div><div class="gsfi" style="position: absolute; top: 1px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0pt; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 1;"></div></div></td><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;" dir="ltr"><tbody><tr><td class="gsib_e"><div></div></td><td class="gsib_b" style="color: rgb(161, 185, 237);">×</td><td class="gsib_f"><div></div></td><td class="gsib_d"><div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: @MADMap, I believe this answer is still helpful (aside from the HTML snippet), because the idea explained here can be easily transferred to Winforms or WPF.

Comment: You really did not have to paste a looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line of HTML to prove your point.

Comment: Maybe the OP is referring to the Google search box in Safari on iOS (probably in a load of other places too). -1

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom painting to paint a little red icon on the rights side of you're control. Add some mouse click code to detect mouse clicks inside the little red icon to activate 'any' custom code.

Answer (score 0):

um sorry dude but in my opinion u can only do this by adding a button ( even inside the textbox) and set it as when it is clicked it clears the textbox

```
textbox.Clear();
```

Good Luck to You , Wish u the best