# Button inside a WinForms textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Do WinForms textboxes have any properties that make an embedded button, at the end of the box, possible?

Something like the favorites button on the Chrome address box:

[image]

I've also seen something like the following in some Excel forms:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I've followed Hans Passant's answer with the addition of a click event handler and it seem to work ok:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Size = new Size(25, textBoxFolder.ClientSize.Height + 2);
    btn.Location = new Point(textBoxFolder.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width, -1);
    btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    btn.Image = Properties.Resources.arrow_diagright;
    btn.Click += btn_Click;     
    textBoxFolder.Controls.Add(btn);
    // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
    SendMessage(textBoxFolder.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
    base.OnLoad(e);
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Getting the button inside the TextBox just requires adding it to the box' Controls collection.  You'll also need to do something reasonable to prevent the text inside the box disappearing underneath the button; that requires a wee bit of pinvoke.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(25, textBox1.ClientSize.Height + 2);
        btn.Location = new Point(textBox1.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width, -1);
        btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        btn.Image = Properties.Resources.star;
        textBox1.Controls.Add(btn);
        // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
        SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
        base.OnLoad(e);  
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

Looked like this while I tested the right margin (should have picked a prettier bitmap):

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks Hans - I'll see if it implements in my project; looks straightforward - find a bitmap: import into project resources; give bitmap name; use your code with new named bitmap ....

Comment: seems to work fine: I also added the line `btn.Click += btn_Click;` so that it does something. I'll amend OP with what I've got as not 100% sure if I have ruined some good code.

Comment: @Hans Passant - This is an awesome solution, thanks. Could you add some detail as to how the SendMessage function works?

Comment: I know this was posted last year (and closed), but I have implemented the code above into a custom textbox class whilst also implementing a watermark feature.  I cannot stop the text from disappearing under the button.  I've even tried to modify the clientsize of the textbox.

Comment: Could you explain `btn.Width << 16` part?

Comment: The MSDN article for EM_SETMARGINS explains it.

Comment: Instead of setting the location-property, I used "btn.Dock = DockStyle.Right" so when my textbox becomes bigger the button keeps to the right.

Comment: @JWiley - .Net's TextBox class does not perform rendering by itself. Instead, it uses the Win32 API's TextBox that is shipped with your version of Windows. The .Net TextBox class wraps the behavior for the Win32 API version, and communicates with it (in order to control its behavior, configure it, etc) by calling SendMessage on the window handle to the underlying control. If TextBox were implemented in plain' ol' C# code using draw calls, SendMessage would not be necessary.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the answer wrapped in a TextBox subclass.

```
public class ButtonTextBox : TextBox {
    private readonly Button _button;

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick { add { _button.Click += value; } remove { _button.Click -= value; } }

    public ButtonTextBox() {
        _button = new Button {Cursor = Cursors.Default};
        _button.SizeChanged += (o, e) => OnResize(e);
        this.Controls.Add(_button); 
    }

    public Button Button {
        get {
            return _button;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnResize(e);
        _button.Size = new Size(_button.Width, this.ClientSize.Height + 2);
        _button.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - _button.Width, -1);
        // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
        SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(_button.Width << 16));
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

}
```

Comment: Sadly using this version has some very weird side-effects. For example, you can set the Button's Image field within the Designer by unfolding the "Button" member under the ButtonTextBox, but once you hit Debug / Run, the Button "forgets" the image, and back in the designer, the setting is gone as well...

Answer (score 6):

I saw in Reflector that Control contains "SendMessage(int,int,int)" method and I found another way.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class ControlExtensions
{
    static BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    static Type[] SendMessageSig = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) };

    internal static IntPtr SendMessage(this Control control, int msg, int wparam, int lparam)
    {
        MethodInfo MethodInfo = control.GetType().GetMethod("SendMessage", flags, null, SendMessageSig, null);

        return (IntPtr)MethodInfo.Invoke(control, new object[] { msg, wparam, lparam });
    }
}
```

Now by overriding WndProc in ButtonTextBox we can achieve desired effect.

```
public class ButtonTextBox : TextBox
{
    Button button;

    public ButtonTextBox()
    {
        this.button = new Button();
        this.button.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.button.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        this.button.Width = 21;
        this.Controls.Add(this.button);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x30:
                int num = this.button.Width + 3;
                this.SendMessage(0xd3, 2, num << 16);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

And I think this is much safer way.

Comment: Up voted the solution but I'm left wondering how it does what it does. What do those numbers stand for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that 0x0030 is the WM_SETFONT message, but why 2, and num << 16 when the wParam should be a handle to the font and the low-order word of lParam a boolean to redraw? Also, do you now think that Hans answer is best? A self contained class is more preferable to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to add a reference to another library, you could consider using the Krypton Toolkit (available at https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton).  The basic toolkit that you should be able to use for free (without the ribbons, navigator, or workspace functionality) does allow you to add "button specs" to various controls (including text boxes) which appear visually just as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small expansion on the accepted solution, to get the button to look and act properly a few tweaks are needed.  Here are tweaks for a search box:

```
    private static readonly int SEARCH_BUTTON_WIDTH = 25;

    private void ConfigureSearchBox()
    {
        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(SEARCH_BUTTON_WIDTH, searchBox.ClientSize.Height + 2);
        btn.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        btn.Image = Properties.Resources.Find_5650;
        btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
        btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        searchBox.Controls.Add(btn);
        this.AcceptButton = btn;
        // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
        SendMessage(searchBox.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello world");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  In order to do something like that you need to create your own User Control.  It can be easily put together from a text box and button.  The difficulty is that if you want similar properties to the text box, you would need to create all them.  In the end it is a lot of code.

Comment: That second screen print I have shown in the OP is from an Excel form so it must be out there somewhere? Could I inherit it from an Excel library?

Comment: @whytheq - Excel in written in C++ using the Windows API and MFC.  It is a custom written control.  You could do something like this in WinForms, but you would need to create custom control.  I would suggest learning WPF.  Much easier to do this

Comment: @thorkia - looks like the excel idea was a bit far fetched but please check out Hans solution + comments to OP.

Answer (score 1):

A minor addition on the nice idea of Hans Passant - if the textbox is resizable, you could add a binding to the underlying button so that it's Location gets adjusted on ClientSize changes as well:

```
    //Adjust the Location of the button on Size Changes of the containing textBox.
    var binding = new Binding("Location", textBox1, "ClientSize");
    binding.Format += (s, e) => e.Value = e.Value is Size ? new Point(((Size)e.Value).Width - btn.Width, -1) : new Point(0, 0);
    btn.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bring together in a control all the code exposed in the post and achieve the following, place a label or a button in the `TextBox`, for all those who want to use it or need it:

```
internal class TxtBox : TextBox
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    Label label = new Label();
    Button btn = new Button();
    Button _button = new Button();

    private Color lblForeColor = Color.Violet;
    private Color lblBackColor = Color.White;
    private EnumTipoDeTexBox eTipoDeTexBox;

    private Font fontLabel = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick 
    { 
        add { _button.Click += value; } 
        remove { _button.Click -= value; } 
    }

    public Font FuenteEtiqueta
    {
        get { return fontLabel; }
        set { fontLabel = value; label.Font = fontLabel; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Button Button
    {
        get
        {
            return _button;
        }
    }

    public Color LblForeColor
    {
        get { return lblForeColor; }
        set 
        { 
            lblForeColor = value;
            label.ForeColor = lblForeColor;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public Color LblBackColor
    {
        get { return lblBackColor; }
        set 
        { 
            lblBackColor = value;
            label.BackColor = lblBackColor;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public EnumTipoDeTexBox TipoDeTexBox
    {
        get { return eTipoDeTexBox; }
        set 
        { 
            eTipoDeTexBox = value; 
            if(eTipoDeTexBox == EnumTipoDeTexBox.Etiqueta)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(btn);
                this.Controls.Add(label);                        //LabelWidth()
                SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(label.Width << 16));
            }
            else if(eTipoDeTexBox == EnumTipoDeTexBox.Boton)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(label);
                CrearBoton();
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
                SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
                btn.Visible = true;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return label.Text; }
        set
        {
            label.Text = value;
            OnResize(EventArgs.Empty);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public TxtBox()
    { 
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        CreaEtiqueta();
        CrearBoton();
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click en boton de textbox");
    }
    private void CreaEtiqueta()
    {
        label.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        label.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.Controls.Add(label);
        label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
        label.Visible = true;
    }

    private void CrearBoton()
    {
        btn.Size = new Size(35, this.ClientSize.Height + 2);
        btn.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width + 1, -1);
        btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        btn.Image = Properties.Resources.search1;
        btn.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
        btn.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true; 
    }

    private int LabelWidth()
    {
        return TextRenderer.MeasureText(label.Text, label.Font).Width;
    }

    private int BotonWidth()
    {
        return TextRenderer.MeasureText(btn.Text, btn.Font).Width;
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        int labelWidth = LabelWidth();
        label.Left = this.ClientSize.Width - labelWidth;
        label.Top = 0;
        label.Width = labelWidth;
        label.Height = this.ClientSize.Height;

         //Ajuste la ubicación del botón en Cambios de tamaño del cuadro de texto que lo contiene.
        /* var binding = new Binding("Location", this, "ClientSize");
        binding.Format += (s, e) => e.Value = e.Value is Size ? new Point(((Size)e.Value).Width - btn.Width, -1) : new Point(0, 0);
        btn.DataBindings.Add(binding);       */                     
    }

    public enum EnumTipoDeTexBox
    {
        Boton = 0,
        Etiqueta = 1
    }
}
```