# Button inside a winforms textbox vb.net

Tags: winforms, button, textbox, controls, addition

i`m vb.net programmer and i found solution for my problem but in c# on this address: [Button inside a winforms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox)

I have converted code to vb.net and it works good except text goes underneath the button here is my converted and c# code, pls tell me where i`m wrong

C# CODE

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Size = new Size(25, textBox1.ClientSize.Height + 2);
    btn.Location = new Point(textBox1.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width, -1);
    btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    btn.Image = Properties.Resources.star;
    textBox1.Controls.Add(btn);
    // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
    SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
    base.OnLoad(e);  
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

My VB.NET CODE

```
     btn.Size = New Size(25, Me.ClientSize.Height + 2)
     btn.Location = New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width - 1)
     btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
     btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default
     btn.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\ansoft\Soljica\texture\tone.png")
     btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
     textbox1.Controls.Add(btn)
     SendMessage(textbox1.Handle, &HED3, CType(2, IntPtr), CType((btn.Width << 16), IntPtr))


<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wp As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

What is wrong with vb.net code if anyone can tell me pls ?

For c# code credits goes to: Hans Passant

Comment: It looks like you added an 'E' when converting the message from C# to VB. `&HED3` should be `&HD3`.

Comment: Tried but still dont work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some of the code related to `Size` and `Location` is wrong. Try this:

```
    btn.Size = New Size(25, textBox1.ClientSize.Height + 2)
    btn.Location = New Point(textBox1.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width - 1, -1)
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    btn.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    btn.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\ansoft\Soljica\texture\tone.png")
    btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
    textBox1.Controls.Add(btn)
    SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, &HD3, CType(2, IntPtr), CType((btn.Width << 16), IntPtr))
```