# Add label inside textbox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, label

I want to make a control which inherits from TextBox and which has a label inside which "sticks" to the right side of the text box and which text is not user-editable but rather is set by a property. How can this be done? I realize there may be many reasons why this UX is a bad idea, but I have to do it this way.

Comment: Does it have to inherit from textbox?

Comment: Well... the existing code uses a textbox so if I could inherit from textbox it would be an easy drop-in replacement without too much refactoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapting from Hans Passant's [Button inside a winforms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869399/719186) answer:

```
public class TextBoxWithLabel : TextBox {

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

  Label label = new Label();

  public TextBoxWithLabel() {
    label.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    label.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    this.Controls.Add(label);
  }

  private int LabelWidth() {
    return TextRenderer.MeasureText(label.Text, label.Font).Width;
  }

  public string LabelText {
    get { return label.Text; }
    set {
      label.Text = value;
      SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(LabelWidth() << 16));
      OnResize(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnResize(e);
    int labelWidth = LabelWidth();
    label.Left = this.ClientSize.Width - labelWidth;
    label.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (label.Height / 2);
    label.Width = labelWidth;
    label.Height = this.ClientSize.Height;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: rofl. i know where i messed up. was trying to set `(IntPtr)3` (in C# language)... i forgot to change it to 2 for right margin. LOL :D

Comment: is there a way to remove 1 px  margin/padding(white color) between label and textbox??

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create a `UserControl` with `TextBox` and a `Label` docked right. That should be pain less and bug free.

As you said you already use `TextBox` to avoid much refactoring you can add all the properties you used in TextBox as "Proxy properties". Something like this:

```
class MyTextBox : UserControl
{
    public int TextLength { get { return textbox.TextLength; } }
    ...
}
```

This can help you to avoid much refactoring.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to replicate all the properties of the textbox to the usercontrol... or refactor the existing code...

Comment: @ian93 How many properties? It is one time job. You can add proxy properties as I shown in my answer. It is not that hard.

Comment: i don't suppose there's a method to draw a fancy border around a usercontrol, like those on textbox? besides rolling your own via OnPaint? if that's the case then just using textbox with a member label is preferable.

Comment: @porkchop In what way inheriting from Textbox and adding a control is good ? TextBox is never designed to be a container control. It won't work well, for instance if you type more characters it will go behind the label I guess. Not sure though.

Comment: sorry, i deleted my code in this post when i realized this is c#. don't use the TB as the container. instead, pass a ref to the parent control to the TB constructor, ie: `(ByVal sender As Control)`, then just add the label to the sender: `sender.Controls.Add(theLabel)`. sorry, VB code again ;p

Comment: @porkchop So we're in same direction right? You're suggesting to add label to `Textbox`'s parent? isn't it? If so that's what my answer is doing ;)

Comment: yea, but without the whole usercontrol, so you can just reference the textbox as a regular textbox with an additional `.textLabel` property just to set the label text. hmm... maybe i'll just convetr my vb code to c#... might take a bit tho... currently busy.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually create a composit control, or simply a UserControl, and put a label and textbox next to each other. Then you can remove the borders around the textbox and surround them with a borderbox to mimic the normal textbox design.

Finally I would make sure that the user controls properties, like `Text` is mapped to the Textbox, so it is easy to use the control as a drop-replacement.

Comment: seems like a lot of complexity for nothing. you can just create a member label in the inherited textbox class and set it's position in the constructor relative to the textbox. simple and efficient.

Comment: @porkchop I think you have the right idea... can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: a borderbox? isn't that css? ;o still can't find a way to do fancy borders on usercontrols, without resorting to OnPaint...