# Notify when control name changes

Tags: c#, controls, notify

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (C#) and have created a user control inherited from a textbox. I need to be able to detect when the control's name changes so that I can execute some other code.

TIA

Comment: You are changing name of control at runtime? Why?

Comment: I am actually doing this at design-time in winforms. This is one of the next steps after getting the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913243/add-label-with-textbox-at-design-time. I am wanting to change the label text with info from the textbox name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured out the proper coding. In the code of the textbox user control I used:

```
private string _name = string.Empty;

public new string Name
{
    get { return base.Name; }
    set
    {
        _name = base.Name = value;
        CreateLabelText(_name);
    }
}

CreateLabelText(string ValueIn)
{
    ...more code here...
}
```