# Dont delete from texbox ,only add some text to it in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a Textbox in my windows form project. that show comments of users. I want when this form show, this Textbox fill from database and user can't delete text of that. they can only add some text to it. how can I do this?

Comment: You mean like disable Delete and backspace `OnKeyPress`? Even that doesn't do it because the user can select any or all of the text and type any character. My advice: Use two textboxes, disable one and append whatever is written in the second textbox to the content of the disabled one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me best solution would be using `disbaled` textbox as it would be difficult to capture `keydown` or `text_changed` event and will also require `AutoPostBack`.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "OriginalContent "; // as example
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String text = TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text;
}
```

Also in the comments @afaolek stated the same solution.

Comment: I don't think that's actually possible, showing two text boxes as one. If you want to show only one text box then simple set `visible=false` of the text box with original content or use a `HiddenField` to store original content. You can also use CSS to hide your text box.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from Hans Passant's [Button inside a winforms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869399/719186) answer and [Add label inside textbox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875101/add-label-inside-textbox-control/23891744#23891744):

```
public class TextBoxWithLabel : TextBox {        
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

      Label label = new Label();

      public TextBoxWithLabel() {
        label.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        label.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        this.Controls.Add(label);
      }

      private int LabelWidth() {
        return TextRenderer.MeasureText(label.Text, label.Font).Width;
      }

      public string LabelText {
        get { return label.Text; }
        set {
          label.Text = value;
          SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(LabelWidth() << 16));
          OnResize(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
      }

      protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnResize(e);
        int labelWidth = LabelWidth();
        label.Left = this.ClientSize.Width - labelWidth;
        label.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (label.Height / 2);
        label.Width = labelWidth;
        label.Height = this.ClientSize.Height;
      }
    }
```

Set database value as LabelText.

```
var txt=new TextBoxWithLabel {LabelText=dbVal};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string current;
private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.current))
    {
        this.current = this.TextBox.Text;
        return;
    }
    if (!this.TextBox.Text.Contains(this.current))
        this.TextBox.Text = this.current;
    else
        this.current = this.TextBox.Text;
}
```