# When would I want to use extern?

Tags: c#

When writing a client app in Winforms, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox) about placing a button within a text box without it interfering with the view of the textbox itself.

In that answer, I noticed the [extern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) modifier, which I hadn't seen in code before.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx):

> "The extern modifier is used to declare a method that is implemented
>   externally. A common use of the extern modifier is with the DllImport
>   attribute when you are using Interop services to call into unmanaged
>   code."

Which is exactly how I'm seeing it used in the related question. I don't understand why it would be necessary to call a user32 external function for this, but that should probably be asked in a separate question.

So my question is, when would extern be the modifier I should use? Why is it better than simply adding the dll to your references and using it directly?

Comment: What about if that library is not a .NET dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse unmanaged DLLs with .NET assemblies.  Just because the extension is `.dll` doesn't mean you can add a reference to it.

Quite simply: If you want to call a C function in an unmanaged DLL, you use `[DllImport(...)]` and the `static extern` modifiers.  Adding it as a reference will not work because it is not a .NET assembly.

If you want to call a method in a managed .NET assembly, you add it as a reference and then you can invoke the method directly using C# code.

Comment: That makes more sense. I think the example of its use with `user32.dll` I saw threw me off. Thanks!