# Reveal password textbox control on windows

Tags: winforms, textbox, passwords

Are there any APIs in Windows to turn a password textbox into something like this:

[image]

So that users will be able to reveal the password for a second while pressing the eye icon right next to textbox. Do you know any P/Invoke like API exists that I can call from my WinForms app?

Answer (score 4):

No need for an API for that, you just toggle it yourself:

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = textBox1.PasswordChar == '\0' ? '*' : '\0';
```

For placing a button inside a textbox, see [Button inside a winforms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869399/719186)

Comment: Yeah, I can do that way but I am curious if there are any native APIs.