# Image inside a TextBox Control C#

Tags: c#, image, textbox

I have a Windows Form with a TextBox and I would like to send some text together with an image inside to a Inbox list of messages. 
For the preview of the image, I used javascript. Selection of the image is done with FileUpload. [Like this preview function.](http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=How%20to%20display%20image%20after%20selecting%20path%20in%20FileUpload%20controller%20without%20clicking)
I want to upload this image to the TextBox and save it in my database. 
Is there a way to include this image. I have only seen RichTextBox. 
What about drag and drop???

[This TextBox is with a button included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox)

[image: This is what I want. I can see that here is the same]
[image: The result]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "upload this image to the TextBox". Please explain.

Comment: I mean inside the TextBox besides text, the image that is selected on preview to go inside this TextBox. And I could have description(text) + image + description(text)+ image.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I hope TaW has provided the proper solution for the question. If not, just comment on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you **can** do is add a Control to the TextBox, which shows an Image.

```
Label imgLabel = new Label();
imgLabel.Image = Image.FromFile(somefile);
imgLabel.AutoSize = false;
imgLabel.Size = imgLabel.Image.Size;
imgLabel.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
imgLabel.Text = "";
imgLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
imgLabel.Parent = textBox1;
// pick a location where it won't get in the way too much
imgLabel.Location = new Point(textBox1.ClientSize.Width - imgLabel.Image.Width, 0);
```

[image]

The image will float above the text, cover it  and get in the way :-(

What you **can't** do is

- Put that control behind the `TextBox`'s text. I don't know of any `Control` that can do that in `Winforms`; both `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` do not support transparency, alas..
- Embed the image in the text and have it flow around it. For this you need to use a `RichTextBox`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the result is very bad. I guess, It is better to save the image in the picture box and display it separately from the text.

Comment: I mark it as an answer, but I am going to change the idea. Will make them separately. Thank you!

Comment: CKEditor can be used.

Comment: Yes, if you can separate them this will be a much better solution. My answer was more for maybe decorating a TextBox with a small icon in a corner, maybe to clear the text. Your example image was added to the question a little after my answer was posted. The question really is: how much interactivity do you want for the user? Enter the text and drag&d drop images? That will be done best with a RichTextBox! (Not that it is very good at placing them inside a text flow, I'm afraid!)