# C# Formatted Text Field That Supports Buttons (like Java JTextField)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, textbox, controls

I've a Winforms C# app that generates a report composed of a hundred or so text messages and a number of actions that can be taken on each message. I want to display this report in a Form, showing each message and a series of buttons below it.

In Java, I would have used a JTextField with the document containing normal text elements plus JButtons, which is nice and snappy and works well.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in C#? Or a control I can use?

My first attempt was to use a Panel and manually populate it with Label and Button controls, but this is incredibly slow to create (although once it's created it's fine).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean slow to create at run time, or laborious to set up in Visual Studio?

Comment: It would be great if You can make an example (image/picture) what You expect the solution to do. I can adjust answer to provide some code after.

Comment: [Button inside a TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

C# Win-Forms works in a different way comparing to Java. Win-Forms does not have snap-like control layout, instead they are being positioned by Px from Top,Left,Right,Bottom.

More java-like layout is using WPF, which is a bit complicated but give You the advance of auto-adjusting sizes/positions.

Generating `TextBoxes`, `Buttons` etc. can be done in pretty good time, You do not need to havy `Panel` or other component in the background. By default Win-`Forms` will create a `Form`, which as a Parent object can host all the `controls` (You can add the items directly to it).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what I was trying to do:
I have a Form in a WinForms application. I want to display the output of a dynamic process within this form, on a scrollable panel, which consists of text and buttons.

What I originally had was something like this (note this is just typed from memory):

```
public void displayOutput(List<Item> items) {

    //create panel to host dynamic content
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    form.Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.AutoScroll = true;
    panel.OnLayout += Do_Layout;

    //create UI controls for each report item
    foreach (Item item in items) {

        //create a label to display the item 
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = item.Messagel
        panel.Controls.Add(l);

        //create a button to perform the item action
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Do something";
        b.Click += ... delegate to perform the action
        panel.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}

public void Do_Layout(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    int y = 0;
    Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls) {

        Size sz = control.GetPreferredSize();
        control.Bounds = new Rectangle(0, y, sz.Width, sz.Height);
        y += sz.Height;
    }
}
```

Which worked just right, but was incredibly slow in the laying out of the panel.

What I found to solve my problem was to suspend the layout of the panel while I was calculating the bounds of all the controls. Just adding the calls to SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() fixed it completely.

```
public void Do_Layout(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    int y = 0;
    Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
    panel.SuspendLayout();  ////////////<<<<< added this

    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls) {

        Size sz = control.GetPreferredSize();
        control.Bounds = new Rectangle(0, y, sz.Width, sz.Height);
        y += sz.Height;  
    }

    panel.ResumeLayout();  ////////////<<<<< added this
}
```