# How to make a rounded textbox in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I already made a rounded button and now im trying to create a rounded textbox. I searched some questions but all is in VB and I don't know that language. And converters are weird. So I tried creating a rounded textbox. So I set the UserPaint to true so I can use OnPaint. It works beautifully on my buttons but it glitches out on my textboxes. It has 2 issues:

- The font size is always the same size no matter what I set it to.
- And when onpaint is called but the text doesn't change it deletes it. That is mostly when I hover my mouse over it.

Code:

```
class RoundedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Color color = Color.White;
    public int borderRadius = 25;
    public RoundedTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        RectangleF Rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        GraphicsPath GraphPath = Functions.FillRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics, brush, Rect, borderRadius);
        this.Region = new Region(GraphPath);
    }
}
```

How I add my textbox:

```
RoundedTextBox usernameTextbox = new RoundedTextBox();
usernameTextbox.Location = new Point(14, 217);
usernameTextbox.Font = new Font(usernameTextbox.Font.FontFamily, 20);
usernameTextbox.Size = new Size(282, this.Height);
usernameTextbox.color = Color.White;
usernameTextbox.Name = "usernameTextbox";
usernameTextbox.Text = "test";
textboxes.Add(usernameTextbox);
usernameTextbox.BackColor = Color.White;
usernameTextbox.borderRadius = 20;
this.Controls.Add(usernameTextbox);
```

[Gif of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/2XweTmk.gifv)

Comment: Of course it does, you are asking it to fill a rounded rectangle after you call the base paint, which covers everything up.

Comment: TextBox is not there to be meddled with.

Comment: UserPaint cannot come to a good end.  You just need to make sure that the text cannot get too close to the corners.  That can be done by using EM_SETMARGINS twice, example [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869399/17034).  A much simpler trick is to set the BorderStyle to None and have the form paint something fancy around it with the same BackColor.

Comment: So It would be like a rounded rectangle with a rectangle in the size of the textbox missing inside it? And where would I call the paint/draw method when not using UserPaint?