SendMessage in VB.NET: using << operator with LPARAM
Using VB.net and following this post, i tried to add a button to a textbox. Everything went fine except for this line of code:
SendMessage(textBoxFolder.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
How do i convert it to VB.NET?
I found help in this post and this article and came to this:
 Dim btnExtend As Button = New Button()
 Dim ptr1 As IntPtr
 Dim ptr2 As IntPtr
 Dim n As Integer = 2
 ptr1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
 ptr2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
 Const EM_SETMARGINS As Integer = &HD3
 Dim p As Integer = btnExtend.Width
 Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr1, n)
 Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr2, p)
 SendMessage(Me.Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, ptr1, ptr2 << 16)
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr1)
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr2)

I got bc30452 error (Operator '' is not defined for types '' and '') on the ptr2 << 16 part. How do i correct that?

"I got bc30452 error". Never just give the error code. ALWAYS provide the error message. We shouldn't all have to look up that code for ourselves to understand what error we're actually dealing with.

For everyone's benefit, that error code indicates that the operator does not exist for the types specified.

Your code is using the pointers completely incorrectly; the code you want to convert is casting regular integers to pointers (because that’s what the function accepts). By contrast, your code allocates memory and passes pointers to that memory to the function. — For your purpose the easiest solution would be to compute the values on regular integers and then initialise the IntPtr parameters from these values using the appropriate constructor.

In fact, the entire code that you wrote can be reduced to two lines: Dim btnExtend as New Button(), followed by SendMessage(Me.Handle, &HD3, New IntPtr(2), New IntPtr(btnExtend.Width << 16)). Everything else in your code is not just unnecessary but actually incorrect.

<< and >> are bit-shift operators. Those operators are defined in VB.NET but, it would appear, not for the IntPtr type. I haven't checked but I would guess that that would be the case in C# too. That means that, if you have an IntPtr to start with, you will need to convert it to an appropriate integral type - probably either Integer or Long - and do the bit-shift on that, then convert back, e.g.
Dim p1 As IntPtr

'...
Dim p2 = CType(CInt(p1) << 16, IntPtr)


No need for CType (which performs opaque conversions), you can use the IntPtr constructor.

I'm not clear why you are using pointers here. The lParam and wParam parameters are not always expected to be pointers. In this case they are not documented as such.
You are also missing actually adding the button to the Controls list.
Dim btnExtend As Button = New Button() With { .Size = SomeSizeHere } 'etc
Me.Controls.Add(btnExtend)

Const EM_SETMARGINS As Integer = &HD3
Const EC_LEFTMARGIN As Integer = &H1
Const EC_RIGHTMARGIN As Integer = &H2

SendMessage(Me.Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, New IntPtr(EC_RIGHTMARGIN), New IntPtr(btnExtend.Width << 16))


I use pointers because i understood (wrongly) that i should use it (according to links in my message)...

The original answer which showed how to do this does not use pointers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868817/button-inside-a-winforms-textbox

I thought that because the solution uses IntPtr, i did not know what it was, looking for some clue here and there led me to my mistakes.
